# model/sql joins in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I join the objects with the models below?

```
User
has_many messages

Message
belongs_to user

Thread
has_many messages
```

I'm trying to get all threads that belong to user X. I would like to join on `message.user_id = user.user_id` and `thread.message_id = message.message_id`. I can do this using `find_by_sql` but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `Message` also `belongs_to :thread?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work: (note that I've added your missing `message belongs_to :thread`)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :threads, :through => :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thread
end

class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, :through => :messages
end
```

This should allow you to do `my_user.threads` and `my_thread.users`.

You can read more about `has_many :through` on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) and the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `Message` model also `belongs_to :thread`, then you should be able to put a `has_many :threads, :through => :messages` in your `User` model. Then you could just do `user.threads` to get all the associated threads.